# CTL_UNSUPPORTED_CALL_FROM_ISR with CrossWorks Library

Tags: c, stm32, isr

I use the CrossWorks target library with a stm32f controller. In my project I have some external pin interrupts enabled. So far they work, and because I more or less stole the configuration from previous projects I would be inclined to say that it should be correct.
All of the ISR handlers look something like that:

```
void __attribute__((interrupt("IRQ"))) EXTI2_TSC_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if ((EXTI_GetITStatus(BUTTON_6_INTERRUPT_LINE) != RESET)) {
        ctl_enter_isr();
        /* Clear the EXTI line 2 pending bit */
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(BUTTON_6_INTERRUPT_LINE);
        if(somecondition)
            globalcounter++;
        else
            myLibFunction();
        ctl_exit_isr();
    }
}
```

All is working perfect, as long `somecondition` is true. If `myLibFunction()` is called, the ctl_handle_error function gets invoked with the CTL_UNSUPPORTED_CALL_FROM_ISR argument and the firmware restarts. So far so clear.

The documentation concerning that error is nonexistent (or I am too dumb to find it). I just have a comment above the ctl_handle_error function, that reads:

```
An interrupt service routine has called a tasking library function
that could block or is otherwise unsupported when called from inside
an interrupt service routine.
```

Assuming this information is correct, what is considered a "blocking function" by CrossWorks? The function does not have any loops. The only flow control used are `if()` statements. No recursion, `while`, `for` or anything else. The overall length in the disassembly is in all cases below 50 instructions.

I am looking for a general explanation (or a documentation link), which functions are deemed acceptable in an ISR and which are not. Or, if my information is wrong, why I get that error generally.

**UPDATE**

My Problem has been solved, thanks to Paul for pointing me to it. But I don't want to close the question just yet. For bonus points I would love to understand how CrossWorks detects a blocking function, and how it can be possible to terminate execution of a function at runtime, when a code block is executed which could be blocking.

I know that this is a heavy edit, but there are no answers as of now, and it fits to the general question about documentation and the "how" behind it.

Comment: Could you post the myLibFunction?

Comment: It seems the library thinks you call a function that does e.g. I/O, an action that requires asynchronousness and waiting for interrupts (i.e., blocking). You cannot call such function from an ISR.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie, you are spot on. In a sub-function of myLibFunction() I had a `debug_print`-call. That is a CrossWorks lib function who prints out debug messages over the jtag interface. I overlooked that. My fault and I apologize for wasting your time. That function was the "blocking" one. I would really find it interesting though, how CrossWorks identifies those functions, or how it terminates execution, when it encounters such a code. I will update the question to encourage people to go deeper into that.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out if you are inside an interrupt or not by looking at hw registers. For example:

```
if(__get_IPSR() & IPSR_THREADED_MODE) {
    /* I am not in interrupt context */
} else {
    /* I am in interrupt context */
}
```

Function __get_IPSR() can be found in core_cmFunc.h when using CMSIS for stm32. I would guess that the function you call will check what context it is running in and act upon it (i.e. terminate or whatever).

Comment: So this "reject blocking functions" works only if the function itsself is checking for a wrong context? If I write a function that does some evil waiting, but no check for the context, this would not be caught?

Comment: That is correct. But you will get serious problems. Watchdog would probably bark, if you implemented one.

Comment: You are right. just tried it with a infinite while loop in the interrupt. Works without CrossWorks complaining. Ooh, now I am disappointed ;)